# Change QTabWidget content background color

Tags: python, layout, pyqt, qwidget

I've been trying to do this for a while but still haven't made it work.

I'm looking to "paint" the background of the tab content to black to be congruent with the graph. By searching online I've tried setting the background color for the layout and creating a Parent widget that would fill to black. None of it worked. Also searched on documentation of PyQt but couldn't find anything useful.

This is my code and below are the pictures of what I have (first) and what I'd like it to be (second).

code:

```
    self.tabBoard = QTabWidget()
    self.tabBoard.setMovable(True)
    self.tabBoard.setSizePolicy(
        QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding,
        QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding
        )
    
    # plot dummy values
    plot = pg.PlotWidget()
    plot.plot(range(0, 20), [3, 4, 2, 4, 7, 3, 4, 2, 4, 7, 3, 4, 2, 4, 7, 3, 4, 2, 4, 7])
    plot.setAspectLocked(lock = True, ratio = 1)

    tabPlotContainer = QVBoxLayout(self.tabBoard)
    tabPlotContainer.setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 5)
    tabPlotContainer.addWidget(plot)

    # table
    tabTable = QWidget()
    tableWidget = QTableWidget(5, 2)
    tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['column1', 'column2'])
    tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)

    tab1hbox = QHBoxLayout()
    tab1hbox.setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 5)
    tab1hbox.addWidget(tableWidget)

    tabTable.setLayout(tab1hbox)

    tabSimple = QWidget()
    tabSimple.setLayout(tabPlotContainer)

    self.tabBoard.addTab(tabSimple, "Plot")
    self.tabBoard.addTab(tabTable, "Table")
```

Pictures:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just add the plot as a new tab? Also, you should *not* create layouts with a parent argument that is not the widget you're going to use for that layout. Especially for widgets that have *their own layout* as QTabWidget.

Comment: @musicamante I've tried using it directly `self.tabBoard.addTab(plot, "Plot")` but didn't work also. The background is still that grey and not that desirable black such as the plot

Comment: But that's the background of the QTabWidget, not of the *tab*. If you change that, you change for all tabs. Maybe you can try with `self.tabBoard.setStyleSheet('QTabWidget { background: black ; }')` (the selector is important!), but I'm not really sure that the macOS style will properly follow that.